Best (performance wise) way to implement operators interms of other ones?
For example I have found that implementing != in terms of == is the exact same assembly as manually doing M0 != that.M0 || M1 != that.M1.
now from my question I want the best code in terms of speed for implanting operators in terms of other ones
// 1
Class operator+(Class const& a,const Class& b) {
     return Class(a) += b; // no rvo
}

// 2 I use this currently. but I will make an rvalue overload for the left hand side argument too
Class operator+(Class const& a,const Class& b) {
     Class c(a);
     c += b;
     return c; // rvo
}

 // 3
Class operator+(Class a,const Class& b) {
     a += b;
     return a; // is there rvo here? it seems from reading cppreference it is not
}



So what is your way of doing the implementation that resulted in most speed?
also please no comments saying "Microoptimizations". I am specifically asking a question about it. I am using the '2' implementation currently but with auto keyword for ease of copy and pasting

out of curiosity, what prevents you to do the same analysis you did for == and != here for + ?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai sadly my pc is broken right now and I cannot measure it right now and I have to wait for 2 weeks and this question has been bugging me.


will not have rvo, it needs to copy local variable into the (caller's allocated) Class instance. Trust your compiler to "see through" your code and still generate highly efficient code. I think the main reason to implement one operator in terms of another is more about preventing bugs than optimizing for speed.


@PepjinKramer less bugs and less mental load when reading the code.

https://godbolt.org/ may provide  assembly too.

@Jarod42 yea I know about it but I am on mobile right now and its UI is really really wonky for mobile

@PepijnKramer yes But I want speed in the process why not.

@PepijnKramer and for example this extremely simple code it didn't optimize it as well as I thought it should cpp struct Vec2 { int x,y; int& operator(std::size_t i) { if(i == 0) return x; else if(i == 1) return y; else __builtin_unreachable(); } }; this doesn't geenrate the most perfomance code as just doing return (&x)[i]; which is UB but it works for thr compilers I care about. so I wouldn't trust my compiler in all cases but I do in most

"So what is your way of doing the implementation?" -- This is opinion-based and off-topic. You were doing better when you focused on "interms of speed".

@JaMiT fixed that was a mistake

@user24551355 UB is UB, it might work on your compiler right now, and in a future version of any compiler it will blow up. do NOT rely on UB EVER!

@PepijnKramer I know. if it breaks I will add a conditional preprocessor check union type punning is UB yet all compilers I care about define it so "UB" is not scary for me if it works and the compiler authors won't break it in the future I will use it for my advantage (in this case speed and less code size). and many libraries do this (thr (&x)[index] trick) such as GLM and ImGuI for example and 0 people complained

I have the feeling you still don't know how much you (and some libraries) are playing with fire. Just watch this : Undefined Behavior in C++: What Every Programmer Should Know and Fear - Fedor Pikus - CppCon 2023

@PepijnKramer i watched it already i watched many topics on ub but 1. this case is widely supported 2. if the ompiler changes it too many code will break with 0 optimization benefits (what are we gonna benefit in terms of performance if I couldn't treat Struct with N members of same type as an array) the standard says this is UB because for example a stupid compiler could insert padding between the members but 0 compilers I care about do this. and as I said all compilers I care about define union type punning so why should I be scared about something they won't break?


if the compiler decides to change it i can simply disable this optimization for this function with CMake



this is offtopic


I even found an open github issue for what I was talking about! https://github.com/g-truc/glm/pull/1308 so I am not even the only one having this performance issue!

@PepijnKramer: If user do it, it is UB, but compiler might generate that assembly code.
